# Use standard USB network device as Access Point

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, ad-hoc-network, wireless-access-point

I have a USB WiFi Device (WISACOM WS-HP1000) which I can use with Linux   to the *rtl8187* driver. I am wondering: is there any way to use it as an Access Point or only the Master mode is able to offer that? The device only seems to support Master and Ad-hoc mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the **[Wasacom](http://wisacom.com/index.php/adaptadores-wifi-usb-80211bg/wisacom-usb)** website that outlines details. Yes, it's in Spanish, but Chrome translated the important part for me:

> - mode access point is to mount an ad-hoc network is not a generic AP

Which in poor-English translation means you can link to another wifi device broadcasting an SSID, but it seems it can't independently broadcast.

Comment: ok, then I guess there is no way. I had the hope that somehow we could use a device in ad-hoc mode as AP (I know, there is an infrastructure mode -master- for that).

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you can depends on hardware support in the wireless device. Access Point operation is more than just software. You'll need to check the specific chipset of your wireless nic to see if ap mode is supported at all.. If it is, then you can explore how to do that.

I believe I've seen the little network gui in Ubuntu Linux provide an interface for putting wifi NICs in to ap mode. So maybe several distros have nice guis for that.

I believe, mjb's suggestion about dd-wrt is cool if you mean to dedicate your machine to being a router.

Comment: the interface supports managed and ad-hoc. That was the question, can I build something similar to an AP in ad-hoc mode?

Answer (score 0):

If the device [is supported](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices), I'd highly recommend installing [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It is an amazing bundle that would fit your needs.

Comment: it's a USB WiFi device, not a router.

Comment: Why don't you mention what the specific USB WiFi device is to clarify instead of having everyone guess? DD-WRT can also be installed as a stand alone OS on many devices, it just might not be as cookie cutter as outlined on the site.

Comment: added the model of the USB device on the question.